# Seperating ConnectionString from source control and be able to perform integrating testing in Azure CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, database-connection, azure-pipelines

I've a WebAPI project and I'm using Azure CI/CD pipeline to deploy it in azure. The project contains unit testing and integration testing. And for integration testing it needs to access database.  But since I don't want to check in my connectionstring to source control, the build pipeline will always fail.

So, the question is what solutions/features or workaround exist that can help me accomplish this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use token replace task to feed your config file with connection string. For that you need to install and add [token replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

and for this configuration:

[image]

you need to have such appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "#{ConnectionString}#"
  },
}
```

and in your pipeline please variable `ConnectionString`:

[image: Variable Azure DevOps]

You can also use variable groups with Azure KeyVault. For that appeoach please check [this blog post](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Access-Azure-Key-Vault-secrets-in-the-Azure-DevOps-Release-Pipelines/).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Key Vault is a good place to securely store secrets such as db server credentials; this keeps them out of source control.

The general approach is:

1. in advance, save the db server password as a keyvault secret
2. in the pipeline, get the db server password using the [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops); it is now available as a secret variable in the pipeline
3. use the db server password in subsequent tasks; either directly, or by substituting into app settings as described in Krzysztof Madej's answer